# Search Functionality broken by the wp 4.2 update

Tags: php, wordpress

Repost from wordpress.stackexchange:

I run a blog site with posts by authors, and I implemented a search that would return results if the search was like an author's name or the search term was contained in a story. I was functioning and properly returned authors who matched the search, but now the search returns every user every single time.

I suspect it has something to do with `WP_User_query since` since that function was updated in 4.2, but I have no idea how I would change it to be compatible.

Here is the search code:

```
add_filter('user_search_columns', 'user_search_columns_bd' , 10, 3);

function user_search_columns_bd($search_columns, $search, $this){
    if(!in_array('display_name', $search_columns)){
        $search_columns[] = 'display_name';
    }
    return $search_columns;
}

add_filter( 'get_meta_sql', 'user_meta_filter', 10, 6 );

function user_meta_filter( $sql, $queries, $type, $primary_table, $primary_id_column, $context ){
    if ( $type !== 'user' ){
        return $sql;
    }

    if ( ! isset( $context->query_vars['meta_query']['replace_and'] ) || $context->query_vars['meta_query']['replace_and'] !== true ){
        return $sql;
    }

    $sql['where'] = preg_replace('/AND/', 'OR', $sql['where'], 1);
    return $sql;
}   


$args = array(
'search'         => $s,
'search_columns' => array( 'user_login', 'user_email'),
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'replace_and' => true, 
    array(
        'key'     => 'first_name',
        'value'   => $s,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'last_name',
        'value'   => $s,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
)
);

// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

**EDIT:**

The relevant sql in array form:

```
Array ( [join] => INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON ( wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id ) [where] => OR ( ( wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name' AND CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%Search%' ) OR ( wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'last_name' AND CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%Search%' ) ) )
```

I'm not quite sure why this sql no longer works in the latest update. It seems to be properly formatted, but it still returns all authors.

Comment: What is the dark magic mentioned? `'replace_and' => true, // Flag for the dark magic`. From my experience magic has a habit of being unreliable.. You might want to check if it's still set at any point that matters

Comment: I pulled that bit of code from somewhere, and it seemed to work until this update. How do you think I code fix for this version of Wordpress? What do you mean "set at any point that matters?"

Comment: I guess the problem is here: `preg_replace('/AND/', 'OR', $sql['where'], 1)`. it's a little "risky": you're changing the first `AND` found in the query, but what if the query changes for some reason? (like for a core update? :) you should find a better way to target the exact `AND`

Comment: I'll look into that. You really don't think it's the meta_query though? I know that they specifically updated that functionality, but I don't really know specifically how, and I believe that my 'args' is properly structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I was right (see comment to question): I had the possibility to test the query before and after the update, and it changed:

```
# BEFORE
SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_users.* FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON ( wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id )  INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_users.ID = mt1.user_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND (user_login LIKE 'test' OR user_email LIKE 'test' OR display_name LIKE 'test') OR ( 
  ( 
    ( 
      ( wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name' AND CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%test%' ) 
      OR 
      ( wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'last_name' AND CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%test%' )
    ) 
    AND 
    mt1.meta_key = 'wp_6_capabilities'
  )
) ORDER BY user_login ASC 


# AFTER
SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_users.* FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON ( wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id )  INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_users.ID = mt1.user_id ) WHERE 1=1 OR ( 
  ( 
    ( 
      ( wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name' AND CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%test%' ) 
      OR 
      ( wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'last_name' AND CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%test%' )
    ) 
    AND 
    mt1.meta_key = 'wp_6_capabilities'
  )
) AND (user_login LIKE 'test' OR user_email LIKE 'test' OR display_name LIKE 'test') ORDER BY user_login ASC
```

So with this line in your code

```
$sql['where'] = preg_replace('/AND/', 'OR', $sql['where'], 1);
```

you're changing the first `AND` found in the query with an `OR`, but as you can see now it targets the wrong one.

In fact now the condition is `WHERE 1=1 OR ...`, that is like saying `ALWAYS`. :)

So as I said earlier in the comment you need to target the right `AND`, but be careful that order can change again.

**Update**

Unfortunately there's no ultimate way to do this because is not native (let's hope it'll be added soon), so you need to rely on changing the right `AND`.

Maybe find a way that works for both the queries (old and new), and to do that you need to change filter hook: use [`pre_user_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_user_query/):

```
add_action('pre_user_query', 'my_custom_users_search');
function my_custom_users_search( $args ) {
    if( isset( $args->query_vars['meta_query']['replace_and'] ) && $args->query_vars['meta_query']['replace_and'] )
        $args->query_where = str_replace(') AND (', ') OR (', $args->query_where);
}
```

Comment: Since 1 just defined the limit as 1, and the first `AND` replaced with an `OR` in order to make the query work, how do I know target the last `AND`? Preferably I would to know a better way to change the query without such a hacky solution.

Comment: I'm not sure how you obtained the full query, but thats what needs to be targeted. The `sql[where]` entry only contains the bit about first and last names. The other part comes from the args array which is added separately. I'm not sure of how to/the best way to alter the final query before it is executed.

Comment: you're right, didn't thought of that. I've updated my answer again, let's hope for the last time :) btw, I've obtained the full query [saving the queries for analisys](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Save_queries_for_analysis)

Comment: After this not working for a while, I realized that the if statement had to check for `$args->query_where['meta_query']['replace_end']` not just `$args->query_where['replace_end']`. Now it works though, so thank you!

Comment: Yes, I had specified to move the `replace_and` outside the `meta_query` arguments, but I realized that it's not necessary, so I removed it. Cool, I'm glad it worked. :)